# visNetwork with R: How to prevent nodes from overlapping with edges

Tags: r, visnetwork

I am using visNetwork (for its dynamic visualizations) to visualize a bipartite graph with 47 nodes.

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
     visIgraphLayout(layout = 'layout.davidson.harel')
```

[image: It came out like this.]

The image above is what it looks like currently and it's the best we could come up with after trying a few layouts (Fruchterman Reingold etc). The problem I have with this is that the edges tend to be so long, so some node pairs are very far apart. Can anyone suggest a layout that prevents nodes from overlapping with edges?

Answer (score 3):

The size of your dataset suggests that it may be acceptable to rely on visNetwork to compute the layout coordinates, rather than igraph via `visIgraphLayout`:

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
    visPhysics(solver = "forceAtlas2Based",
               forceAtlas2Based = list(gravitationalConstant = -100))
```

[Layout via visNetwork](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tf3ve.jpg)

For comparison, the same data plotted with igraph:

```
visNetwork(nodes, edges) %>%
   visIgraphLayout(layout = 'layout.davidson.harel')
```

[Layout via igraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zKXqE.jpg)